# Is there a way to configure version property without using @Version annotation in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, optimistic-locking, mongotemplate

I have my own POJOs contained complex class hierarchy (embedded documents with inheritance support). I have already made support of mapping with inheritance using ConfigurableTypeInformationMapper without using @TypeAlias. And also I would like my POJOs do not depend on 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb' framework, but adding OptimisticLocking feature requires annotating fields with @Version annotation. Is there a way to configure version property without using @Version annotation in Spring Data MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

For those who interested in how not to depend on @Version annotation in your POJOs look at MyCachingMongoPersistentProperty class.

```
    class MyMongoMappingContext : MongoMappingContext() {

    private var fieldNamingStrategy: FieldNamingStrategy? = null

    override fun setFieldNamingStrategy(fieldNamingStrategy: FieldNamingStrategy?) {
        if (fieldNamingStrategy == null) {
            this.fieldNamingStrategy = DEFAULT_NAMING_STRATEGY
            super.setFieldNamingStrategy(DEFAULT_NAMING_STRATEGY)
        } else {
            this.fieldNamingStrategy = fieldNamingStrategy
            super.setFieldNamingStrategy(fieldNamingStrategy)
        }
    }

    override fun createPersistentProperty(
        property: Property,
        owner: MongoPersistentEntity<*>,
        simpleTypeHolder: SimpleTypeHolder
    ): MongoPersistentProperty {
        return MyCachingMongoPersistentProperty(
            property, owner, simpleTypeHolder, fieldNamingStrategy
        )
    }

    companion object {

        private val DEFAULT_NAMING_STRATEGY: FieldNamingStrategy =
            PropertyNameFieldNamingStrategy.INSTANCE

    }

}

class MyCachingMongoPersistentProperty(
    property: Property,
    owner: MongoPersistentEntity<*>,
    simpleTypeHolder: SimpleTypeHolder,
    fieldNamingStrategy: FieldNamingStrategy?
) : CachingMongoPersistentProperty(property, owner, simpleTypeHolder, fieldNamingStrategy) {

    override fun isVersionProperty(): Boolean {
        return SchemaConstants.VERSION_PROPERTY_NAME == super.getFieldName()
    }

}
```